# Assertion when running synthesis for Verilog UART

Tags: verilog, uart, assertion

I'm pretty new to Verilog/FPGA programming and I'm trying to realize a UART. My source is based on the tutorial of fpga4fun.com. My code is as follows:

```
module async_transmitter(
    input clk,
    input TxD_start,
    input [7:0] TxD_data,
    output TxD,
    output TxD_busy
);

parameter ClkFrequency = 25000000;  // 25MHz
parameter Baud = 115200;

generate
    if(ClkFrequency<Baud*8 && (ClkFrequency % Baud!=0)) ASSERTION_ERROR PARAMETER_OUT_OF_RANGE("Frequency incompatible with requested Baud rate");
endgenerate

// ... do something more

endmodule
```

The given values are the default values as included in the tutorial. But when I try to synthesize the code, it always fails at the if condition.

For the async_receiver I'm getting a similar result:

```
module async_receiver(
    input clk,
    input RxD,
    output reg RxD_data_ready = 0,
    output reg [7:0] RxD_data = 0,
    output RxD_idle,  // asserted when no data has been received for a while
    output reg RxD_endofpacket = 0  // asserted for one clock cycle when a packet has been detected (i.e. RxD_idle is going high)
);

parameter ClkFrequency = 25000000; // 25MHz
parameter Baud = 115200;

parameter Oversampling = 8;

generate
    if(ClkFrequency<Baud*Oversampling) ASSERTION_ERROR PARAMETER_OUT_OF_RANGE("Frequency too low for current Baud rate and oversampling");
    if(Oversampling<8 || ((Oversampling & (Oversampling-1))!=0)) ASSERTION_ERROR PARAMETER_OUT_OF_RANGE("Invalid oversampling value");
endgenerate


// ... do something more

endmodule
```

PlanAhead tells me that both if conditions were met for the receiver side. But for example, when I calculate Oversampling * Baud (8 * 115200) = 921600 which is in fact smaller than 25000000. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the error you're getting during synthesis?

Comment: It tells me "[HDLCompiler 24] ASSERTION_ERROR expects 0 arguments" because the ASSERTION MODULE was defined without any arguments to be able to throw an assertion error if necessary. The ASSERTION_ERROR-Module is defined as 
"module ASSERTION_ERROR();
endmodule"
It is included in the example from fpga4fun.com...

Answer (score 0):

You have the module definition for `ASSERTION_ERROR`, then, which would've been my first guess.

I've tried the HDL on Quartus 13.0sp1 using the same parameters, and I don't get any errors - I don't currently have ISE/PlanAhead, so it could be isolated to that. I can confirm that the generate "works" correctly by decreasing `ClkFrequency` or increasing `Baud`. Double-check that you've got the correct values, and that they aren't being over-written by whatever module instantiates `async_transmitter`.

That said, if you feel confident that the values are correct, you could simply comment out the `generate` block - it doesn't actually generate anything, after all.

Comment: I finally solved the issue by commenting out the line and everything works fine. Thanks for your suggestion :)